# Creating pages from html

Tags: html, static

I am trying to print from pdf, and each page needs to have a footer. 
I was thinking whether I could define a static table:

```
--------
|_______|
|       |
|       |
|_______|
|_______|
```

The bottom part and top part are static and contain the header and footer. The middle part must be dynamic and is filled in using actionscript. When the end of the middle cell was reached with the stuff we put in, I want to create a whole new static table.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good idea to create static table for content. you can easily fetch data and insert into this. You need to make a unique ID for each page.

Comment: Do you know where I can find an example for this somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have. I just tell you scenario.

Comment: Process seems good. Need to insert in the database on the basis of the pages id and need to fetch data on the basis of ID. If you like my answer vote my answer. Thanks